# Mac OSX Short operation system freeze

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, monterey

**Symptom**:
My IMac 5K (Ultimo 2014, Monterey) always freezes for a short time, i.e. no matter if I briefly open the Finder, select folders or open a setting, then the ball icon always appears for about 1 minute or less, so it is not app, folder specific.

**Analysis**:
My guess is, it's the hard drive problem so I ran Disk Utility and did a first aid check. The apps found several permission errors, however the app does not repaired it.
In OSX system > Disk Utility > Disk and Container selected > First Aid started.
There are also no error messages in the system logs that would match to the freezing time.

**Attempted troubleshooting**:

1. **Start Disk Utility via CMD+R**: It doesn't happen, the screen stays black. I read that the partition is damaged or not present, that's probably why it doesn't appear.
2. **Reinstall via Internet CMD+Alt+R**: It loads, but later I receive the error 2003f appears (network problem). Then I connect the iMac directly via LAN and then I receive 1006F. I execute Command + Option + P + R performed, then the installation progressed and I received 2003F again.
3. **Created bootable USB stick**: I thought the connection to the server seems to be unstable, so I created a Bootable USB OSX Monterey (using a Mac mini Intel). When booting, I pressed ALT and selected the installation, then a crossed out icon appears, although the system is compatible with the Mac and the installation is also bootable from another Mac.

I don't know, how to fix the problem with the iMac. Maybe the hardware is broken, because I got a 1006F error...
Maybe one more has an idea how I can fix the problem.
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Two things… the 2014 iMac can't run Monterey natively - https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-3.5-27-inch-aluminum-retina-5k-late-2014-specs.html - & the usual problem with iMacs of that age is trying to run a modern OS expecting to be on SSD from a HDD.

Comment: It *could* be the HD in early stages of failing. It could also be just a standard and slow physical rotating HD. Replacing the HD with an SSD should make the Mac substantially more responsive, if you are up for having it replaced or doing it yourself. You will likely find instructions on fixit.com that will show you how to do a SSD/HD swap, if you are inclined to do it.

Comment: thank you, yes right Monterey is to new, that's why I cannot use it. The solution was to replace the HDD with SSD. But after I change the SSD I could install only the operation system 11.7 the newest version doesn't work anymore.